# validating input choice & loop until get one of 4 options

Tags: python, loops, validation, input

> I have tried so many variations here to no avail. I have a menu with 4 options, I'm trying to loop if 
>   options 1, 2, 3 or 4 is not selected whilst printing out a response and reprompting a choice of only 1, > 2, 3 or 4.  I've tried:

```
print("Options:")
print("Option 1")
print("Option 2")
print("Option 3")
print("Option 4")
choice = int(input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? "))
while choice not in ['1','2','3','4']:
    print: ("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4. ")
    choice = int(input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? "))
```

> and

```
print("Options:")
print("Option 1")
print("Option 2")
print("Option 3")
print("Option 4")
choice = input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? ")
while choice not '1' and choice not '2' and choice not '3' and choice not '4':
    print: ("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4. ")
    selection = input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? ")
```

> and

```
print("Options:")
print("Option 1")
print("Option 2")
print("Option 3")
print("Option 4")
choice = int(input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? "
    while choice != '1' and user_input != '2' and user_input != '3' and choice != 4:
    choice = int(input("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4. "))
```

> I'm getting a range or errors from syntax errors to incorrect output (will not print "Please enter 1,
>   2, 3 or 4. " and will not loop. Only after something very simple, don't want to use a quit
>   statement - where am I going wrong here please?

Comment: Use this `while choice!=1 and choice!=2 and choice!=3 and choice!=4:`

Comment: Hi @dt170, yeah, I'd tried that earlier too - but when I do that, it also ignores the print command before requesting re-input?

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting an integer and you are looking for it as char, change your validation list to integers and your first option works:

```
print("Options:")
print("Option 1")
print("Option 2")
print("Option 3")
print("Option 4")
choice = int(input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? "))
while choice not in [1,2,3,4]:
    #print: ("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4. ")
    print("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4. ")
    choice = int(input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? "))
```

[This work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfg9C.png)

Comment: Hi @ Marvik, I had tried that solution too - but when I run the module and enter '5', for example, it ignores the command to print "please enter 1, 2 3 or 4" and just requests int input again, so I thought that made the print command obsolete for some reason?

Comment: helps if I @ you properly!

Comment: @YVB It is for the two points after the print, they are not necessary

Comment: I had to restart the kernel to be able to run it again, maybe you need it too